# Using Simple Html Dom to remove some elements

Tags: php, html, simple-html-dom

[This](http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml) is the page I'm trying to parse using Simple Html Dom. I've gotten 90% of the functionality done, but since I'm new to the library I'm not quite sure to do this.

I want to scrape the **text of each news item**, but since the text is inside the `<p>`element, using something like `->innertext` bring everything inside, including the link.

Here's what I've tried:

```
<h1>Scraper Noticias</h1>

<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

class News {
    var $image;
    var $fechanoticia;
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sourceurl;

    function get_image( ) {
        return $this->image;
    }

    function set_image ($new_image) {
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    function get_fechanoticia( ) {
        return $this->fechanoticia;
    }

    function set_fechanoticia ($new_fechanoticia) {
        $this->fechanoticia = $new_fechanoticia;
    }

    function get_title( ) {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function set_title ($new_title) {
        $this->title = $new_title;
    }

    function get_description( ) {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function set_description ($new_description) {
        $this->description = $new_description;
    }

    function get_sourceurl( ) {
        return $this->sourceurl;
    }

    function set_sourceurl ($new_sourceurl) {
        $this->sourceurl = $new_sourceurl;
    }
}

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml');

$parsedNews = array();

// Find all news items.
foreach($html->find('#cont2 p') as $element) {

    $newItem = new News;

    // Parse the news item's thumbnail image.
    foreach ($element->find('img') as $image) {
        $newItem->set_image($image->src);
        //echo $newItem->get_image() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's post date.
    foreach ($element->find('span.fechanoticia') as $fecha) {
        $newItem->set_fechanoticia($fecha->innertext);
        //echo $newItem->get_fechanoticia() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's title.
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $title) {
        $newItem->set_title($title->innertext);
        //echo $newItem->get_title() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's source URL link.
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $sourceurl) {
        $newItem->set_sourceurl("http://www.uvm.cl/" . $sourceurl->href);
    }

    // Parse the news items' description text.
    echo $link; //This is the entire <p> tag. How can I get just the text. Not the link?

} 

?>
```

Comment: I just tested it and it returns 7 links. Are you just wanting the text and strip the links?

Comment: @Paul: Exactly. :) That's exactly the issue I'm having. I want the text, without the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution I found. Although if I can improve the code, it would be appreciated.

```
<h1>Scraper Noticias</h1>

<?php

include('simple_html_dom.php');

class News {
    var $image;
    var $fechanoticia;
    var $title;
    var $description;
    var $sourceurl;

    function get_image( ) {
        return $this->image;
    }

    function set_image ($new_image) {
        $this->image = $new_image;
    }

    function get_fechanoticia( ) {
        return $this->fechanoticia;
    }

    function set_fechanoticia ($new_fechanoticia) {
        $this->fechanoticia = $new_fechanoticia;
    }

    function get_title( ) {
        return $this->title;
    }

    function set_title ($new_title) {
        $this->title = $new_title;
    }

    function get_description( ) {
        return $this->description;
    }

    function set_description ($new_description) {
        $this->description = $new_description;
    }

    function get_sourceurl( ) {
        return $this->sourceurl;
    }

    function set_sourceurl ($new_sourceurl) {
        $this->sourceurl = $new_sourceurl;
    }
}

// Create DOM from URL or file
$html = file_get_html('http://www.uvm.cl/noticias_mas.shtml');

$parsedNews = array();

// Find all news items.
foreach($html->find('#cont2 p') as $element) {

    $newItem = new News;

    // Parse the news item's thumbnail image.
    foreach ($element->find('img') as $image) {
        $newItem->set_image($image->src);
        //echo $newItem->get_image() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's post date.
    foreach ($element->find('span.fechanoticia') as $fecha) {
        $newItem->set_fechanoticia($fecha->innertext);
        //echo $newItem->get_fechanoticia() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's title.
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $title) {
        $newItem->set_title($title->innertext);
        //echo $newItem->get_title() . "<br />";
    }

    // Parse the news item's source URL link.
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $sourceurl) {
        $newItem->set_sourceurl("http://www.uvm.cl/" . $sourceurl->href);
    }

    // Parse the news items' description text.
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $link) {
        $link->outertext = '';
    }

    foreach ($element->find('span') as $link) {
        $link->outertext = '';
    }

    foreach ($element->find('img') as $link) {
        $link->outertext = '';
    }

    echo $element->innertext;

} 

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `innertext` instead of `outertext`

```
    foreach ($element->find('a') as $sourceurl) {
    echo $sourceurl->innertext . "<br />";
    }
```